# JavaScript confirm box not working in php

Tags: php, javascript

```
echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?id=$id' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?');'><center>Delete</center></a></td>";
```

i want a prompt msg as the user will click on "delete" if he/she will press "ok" then it will redirect to a page where the data will get deleted and if he/she will press "cancel" then nothing will happen.
by using the above code i m not able to get my prompt box nd data is directly getting deleted.

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing up `'` and `"` here.

```
echo "<td> <a href ='del.php?id=$id' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\");'><center>Delete</center></a></td>";
```

Your code would have outputted this:

```
<td> 
  <a href ='del.php?id=123' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?');'><center>Delete</center></a>
</td>
```

Even from SOs syntax highlighting you can see, that there is something wrong in the `onclick` handler. There you have `'` inside of other `'`. So at that point you should replace the inner `'` with `"`. To do so in PHP (where you have surrounding `"` as well), just escape the inner `"` by using `\"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to PHP. The onclick handler of an `a` tag will not stop the browser from changing location. You could do something like this instead:

```
echo"<td> <a href='javascript:void' onclick='if (confirm(\"Are you sure?\")) window.location=\"del.php?id=$id\";'><center>Delete</center></a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the complexity you can code as:

```
$confirm="return confirm('Are you sure?');";
echo "<td> <a href ='del.php?id=$id' onclick='$confirm'><center>Delete</center></a></td>";
```

OR

```
echo "<script> function isConfirm() { if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;}";
echo "<td> <a href ='del.php?id=$id' onclick='return isConfirm()'><center>Delete</center></a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"<td><a href ='del.php?id=$id' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\"><center>Delete</center></a></td>";
```

You missed double quotation onclick=\" \";

your confirm box wasn't detected by the program because of single quotations >> onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?');'